# Combine multiple image files into a single PDF file

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, pdf, pdf-generation

What's a good utility for combining different image files (e.g. PNGs or JPGs) into a single PDF file, with no quality loss (or minimal quality loss)?

Required features:

- Libre
- Gratis
- Command-line
- Runs on Linux
- Runs on x86_64 machines

Desired features:

- Cross platform
- Fast

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use imagemagick on each image individually:

```
convert foo.png foo.pdf
```

then combine them all with

```
pdfunite foo.pdf bar.pdf baz.pdf output.pdf
```

but make sure to list the PDFs in order. `pdfunite` is part of the [Poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) project, and is FOSS; and so is [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/).

**Caveat: imagemagick re-compresses (and possibly even changes the resolution) during conversion, so this doesn't really wrap the images in a PDF.**

Answer (score 0):

A GUI utility for doing this is [`gscan2pdf`](http://gscan2pdf.sourceforge.net/). While it's oriented towards scanning images, it supports combining images in a PDF very easily:

1. Launch gscan2pdf.
2. On the menu, choose File | Open.
3. Choose your files.
4. On the menu, choose File | Save.
5. You can usually ignore the resulting dialog; press Save and choose a target filename.

That's it! Quick and easy and you don't have to memorize anything.

`gscan2pdf` supports several common formats including JPEG, PNG and TIFF - and also images already wrapped inside a PS or PDF file, but those need to be one-page PS or PDF files.